# “help” decision tree by tying 2 features together

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Assuming I have in my dataset 2 (or more) features that are for sure linked (for example: feature B indicates the amount of relevance of feature A), is there a way I could design a decision tree that will tie both features together (the obvious split would be if feature B is big enough split by A and if not ignore A)?
In other words: I'm looking for a way to "help" my decision tree to not test feature A before testing feature B. Plus, not to look on the improvement of each feature individually, but on the improvement of "B and afterwords A" . Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `splitter` parameter to do so in `DecisionTreeClassifier`.
Create your own implementation to do so.

And use:

```
my_decision_tree = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(splitter=mySplitter)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how?

Comment: Currently, I cannot provide you with a working example. But, this was the only solution when I looked for a similar problem a year ago. Another approach would be to split the feature set on `feature b`. And then run decision tree on the solution set. This makes sure that split is made on `feature b` first.

Comment: @Binyamin Even, please do share your approach later.

Answer (score 2):

You have several possibilities,

#### Add new features encoding what you want to say

You can give a third feature that is a linear, polinomial, or logical combination of feature A and B and hope that the system will figure it all by itself. For this, sklearn proposes [Polinomial Features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) class and all the making modules of numpy.

For example, if feature B encodes the amount of relevance of feature A. Suppose that B goes from 0 to 10, encoding the amount of relevance. You can make new features A_0, *A_2, A_i, ..., A_9* that are the value of A if *B > i* and *-10000* everywhere else.

You can also make a third feature that is A+B or A*B or A*B^2. The problem with these is that they are harder to give a good interpretation of the results after fitting the decision tree.

#### Partition your data before hand

You can partition your data using the criteria you want and then fit different trees for each sub dataset. For example, you can partition your data in two groups, B > 5 and B <= 5

#### Make different trees

You can fit a primary tree only on features from B, and then, for each leaf of the decision tree, you can now fit a new tree considering features from both A and B.
This can be messy in terms of code, as you'll need handle several classifiers and ensure enough samples per leaf so further trees can be fit.

#### Make your own splitter function

If you really want to have the hand on how the tree decides at each step You will have to do as Aditya proposes, in that case you'll need to create your own splitter function.

The default splitter in sklearn is implemented [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L304)

You will need to modify it to take into account all the variables of your problem

Comment: Good Answer! I would say there is another option: **Let the tree figure it out**: Decision trees are designed to do exactly the kind of hierarchical decisions required by the OP. If this prior hypothesis is apparent in the data, an appropriate learning algorithm should find to split B before A (perhaps greedy learning is not the best choice here). If the prior hypothesis is not apparent in the data there are two choices: **1.** question both the hypothesis and the data. **2.** augment the training data with artificial examples with a clear B -> A preference.